# How filter on calculated field (append) in Eloquent Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have calculated property 'price' in model Room.

```
protected $appends = ['price'];

public function getPriceAttribute()
{
    if ($this->action) return $this->action_price_per_meter*$this->area;
    return $this->price_per_meter*$this->area;
}
```

When i filter Rooms by this virtual field ...

```
$rooms = Room::where('price','<',100000)->get();
```

of course i got error  - Column 'price' not found

How to solve this problem in Laravel way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eloquent has a `whereRaw` method which allows you to construct that segment of the query manually.

In your case you need the equivalent of the model's method in SQL:

```
->whereRaw('price_per_meter * area < 100000')
```

It'll be more complicated depending on what your `action` column is doing but that should serve as a starting point.

Comment: How make depending on action column?